# Rails Model with attribute that has different value on different day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Table, the Table has a attributes called price. And price may change everyday whenever owner of the table wants to. How can I keep track of all the values of Price so that I can return what was the price of table on 1st JAN 2017 or any other past dates.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This question is far too broad to answer currently.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to make price as a new model something like `TableCalendarPrice` which has two attributes `date` and `price` and a reference to the `Table` model.

Answer (score 0):

You can Keep a history of price changes over time

Create a new model PriceHistory

```
rails g model PriceHistory price:float table:references
```

and in Table Model, create relationship

```
has_many :price_history
```

Now in Table model create a before save option

```
before_update :set_price_history

def set_price_history
   if price_changed?
      a = PriceHistory.new(table_id: :id,  price: :price)
      a.save
   end
end
```

It will create `created_at` entry automatically which can be compared with  date to get price on previous dates.

Hope this helps..